# Inserting values from drop down list and text box to the database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

Why this code is not work I try to insert student ID and student name from text box table and Major, Course from drop down list

```
int sID = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
string Name = TextBox2.Text;
var mjr = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
var crs = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;

string registered = "insert into Registered (Student_name, StudentID, Major, Course) values(@sName ,@SID, @major , @course)";

while (reader.Read())
{
    ints.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));

    if (a.Count() <= ints.Count() && !a.Except(ints).Any())
    {
        SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand(registered, con);

        com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("sName", Name);
        com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("SID", sID);
        com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("major", mjr);
        com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("course", crs);
        com4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "@" with scalar attributes names

```
 com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", Name);
 com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", sID);
 com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@major", mjr);
 com4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", crs);
 com4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: [Never suggest using `AddWithValue` please](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I am not suggesting anything here, just fixing above code. :)

Comment: Then suggest how to do it properly!

Comment: There is no serious reason why AddWithValue shouldnt be used. In fact It helps avoiding sql injection.

Comment: Read the link I posted, that is written by a Microsoft MVP who [really know what he's talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn).

Comment: @DavidG what can I use then

Comment: @SweetGarl [Read the link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) I put above, it explains everything